# Migrating a token from Counterparty to Ethereum

Tags: erc-20

I am having a token in Counterparty blockchain and I'd like to migrate it over to Ethereum. The token is currently being traded on some of exchanges.

What strategies there are to take here? Are there any past examples?

I was thinking

- Taking a blockchain snapshot and crediting Ethereum tokens to users to an address with a matching public key on Ethereum chain
- Having a special address where Counterparty tokens are send to be burned, then have a bot to read the transactions and issue corresponding tokens to a given public address on Ethereum chain

Comment: Did you end up doing this? I can think of some ways, but they are prohibitively expensive for on chain storage.

Comment: The migration is live.